# Stocktwit symbol for foreign stocks

Tags: stocktwits

Is there a rule for stocktwits symbols for stocks that are traded on non-US stock exchanges? For example British Telecom is traded on the London Stock Exchange and it's symbol is LON: BT.A.

How do I format the stocktwits symbol for this stock? Is it $LON:BT.A or $LONBTA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StockTwits does not currently support the London Stock Exchange but might in the future. Only forex, US exchanges and the Toronto Stock Exchange are currently supported

Comment: Hi Eric, Is there a forum to start talking about here that might be monitored by StockTwits?

Comment: How do you handle Toronto Stock Exchange handles?

Comment: There is no forum right now. We check Redit, StackOverflow and our support email at support@stocktwits.com regularly.

TSX tickers end in .CA on StockTwits. For example BB.CA is Blackberry for the Toronto Stock Exchange.

Comment: So BTA.UK would fit your naming scheme then.